# React form input values in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, bulma

I am using NextJS with bulma CSS to create a simple application. I have this following form:

```
const MyPage = () => {
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
const [secondName, setSecondName] = useState('')

const updateFirstName = event => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value)
}

const updateSecondName = event => {
    setSecondName(event.target.value)
}

const createUser = async() => {
   // Todo: perform some action with firstName and secondName
}

return (
<section className='mt-5'>
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='field'>
            <label className='label'>My Form</label>
            <div className='control'>
                <input onChange={updateFirstName} className='input' type='type' placeholder='Enter First Name'></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='field'>
            <div className='control'>
                <input onChange={updateSecondName} className='input' type='type' placeholder='Enter Second Name'></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={createUser} className='button is-primary'>Create</button>
    </div>
</section>
)
}
export default MyPage
```

I have to call `updateFirstName` and `updateSecondName` on every input change.
I want to get these input field's value on `createUser()` function call only. Please suggest how to do it or any other better approach. I want to eliminate firstName and secondName variables, and directly access entered input in the `createUser()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a controlled input. You can quit managing the state and access the value old way using plain vanilla JS.

Make sure to add name attribute with all the input fields.

```
function createUser() {
    
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".field input")
   let data = {}
   inputs.forEach(input => {
      data[input.name] = input.value
   })
   /**
    This would yield you
    {
      'firstname': 'value',
      'secondName': 'value' 
    }
   **/
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. There are other forms on the page as well, so `(".field input")` will yield all the input. Is there any other solution to filter fields only in this particular form?

I want to eliminate firstName and secondName variables.

Comment: Yes you can give id to the div containing all those input fields you want to select and run document.querySelectorAll("#outer-div-id input"). This would only select the input fields you want to select

Answer (score 0):

Please change your input fields as shown below:

```
 <input onChange={(e)=>createUser(e,'firstName')} className='input' type='type' placeholder='Enter First Name'></input>
 <input onChange={(e)=>createUser(e,'lastName')} className='input' type='type' placeholder='Enter First Name'></input>
```

Then in your update your createUser function as shown below:

```
const createUser = (event, element) => {
   if(element==='firstName') {
      setFirstName(event.target.value)
   }

   if(element==='lastName') {
      setLastName(event.target.value)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternatively with this useRef() hook,

```
const MyPage = () => {

const firstName = useRef();
const secondaName = useRef();

const createUser = async() => {
    
   // Todo: perform some action with firstName and secondName
   console.log(firstName.current.value, secondName.current.value)  // It will prints the value that is typed by the user in both the textfields
  
}

return (
<section className='mt-5'>
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='field'>
            <label className='label'>My Form</label>
            <div className='control'>
                <input ref={firstName} className='input' type='type' placeholder='Enter First Name'></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='field'>
            <div className='control'>
                <input ref={secondName} className='input' type='type' placeholder='Enter Second Name'></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={createUser} className='button is-primary'>Create</button>
    </div>
</section>
)
}
export default MyPage
```

Comment: Ideally, I do not want to create separate variables for form variables in my program. Not sure if it is best use case for useRef() hook

Answer (score 0):

You can write a handler function

Firstly, you should add all variables to same state.

```
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    secondName: ""
  });
```

and you should give a name to inputs like this.

```
  <input
  className="input"
  onChange={onChangeHandler}
  name="firstName" //name attribute must same your state variable
  placeholder="Enter First Name"
  />

  <input
  className="input"
  onChange={onChangeHandler}
  name="secondName" //name attribute must same your state variable
  placeholder="Enter Second Name"
  />
```

and your handler function should like this

```
  const onChangeHandler = (e) =>
    setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

and this function take your input value and set your state who same name.

Full code

```
export default function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    secondName: ""
  });

  const onChangeHandler = (e) =>
    setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const sendData = () => {
    console.log(userInfo);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section className="mt-5">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="field">
            <label className="label">My Form</label>
            <div className="control">
              <input
                className="input"
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                name="firstName"
                placeholder="Enter First Name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <div className="control">
              <input
                className="input"
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                name="secondName"
                placeholder="Enter Second Name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button onClick={sendData} className="button is-primary">
            Create
          </button>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-pasteur-uglbri?file=/src/App.js:58-1264